# Magento 2 : which event should I use when want to add free item in cart?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

when purchase a Product X, want to add product Y automatically to code.
It saves in cart but 'save' function is goes into loop because it also has event as '**checkout_cart_save_after**'.

events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_save_after"> <!-- checkout_cart_save_after, checkout_cart_product_add_after -->
    <observer name="add_gift_to_cart" instance="Product\AddGift\Observer\AddFreeProductToCart" />
</event>
</config>
```

and observer :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $isFreeItem = 0;

    foreach($items as $item) {
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        $_product = $this->_product->create()->load($productId);
        $has_free_product = $_product->getHasFreeProduct();

        if($has_free_product){
            $free_product_sku = $_product->getFreeProductSku();

            if($free_product_sku){
                $isFreeItem = 1;
            }

        }
    }

    if($isFreeItem) {
        $free_product = $this->_product->create()->load($_product->getIdBySku($free_product_sku));
        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $free_product->getId(), //product Id
            'qty'   => 1, //quantity of product
            'price' => 0
        );

        $free_product->setPrice(0.00);
        $this->_cart->addProduct($free_product, $params);
        $this->_cart->save();
    }
}
```

Please suggest any solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to perform observer code at add to cart product time. Right?

Comment: @RohanHapani yes, It adds to cart now. but it shows 0 price at only in cart, I want to set price zero at through out the order process for free product.

Comment: Check answer. Now, you can set your price in free product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** event for add custom product when add to cart action perform. Follow these below steps :

> **app/code/Vendor/Magento/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
    <observer name="add_gift_to_cart" instance="Vendor\Magento\Observer\AddFreeProductToCart" />
</event>
</config>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Magento/Observer/AddFreeProductToCart.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Magento\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddFreeProductToCart implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $quoteItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $free_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(1);
            $params = [
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product_id' => $free_product->getId(), //product Id
                'qty' => 1, //quantity of product
            ];

            $this->cart->addProduct($free_product, $params);
            $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($free_product);
            $productItem->setCustomPrice(153); //Set Custom Price
            $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(153); //Set Custom Price
            $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true); //Enable super mode on the product.
            $this->cart->save();
        }
    }

    public function getProductQuote($product) {
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
        return $cartItems;
    }
}
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: It works perfectly.. thanks @Rohan Hapani

Comment: Glad to help you !! Happy coding :)